# Modal confirm button doesn´t work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I do have a bootstrap modal confirm dialog with two buttons: continue and cancel, the cancel actions works well(just close the modal window) but the continue doesn´t work, this is the code of the button that triggers the modal window:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-cancelar" data-target="#basic" data-toggle="modal">
Cancelar
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
</button>
```

this is the modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basic" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">book Delete Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you Sure!!! You want to delete this Ad?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btnContinueDelete">Continue</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery click event of the button continue with id="btnContinueDelete"

```
$('#btnContinueDelete').click(function () {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action(actionName: "TipoEvento", controllerName: "Home")';
});
```

my problem is that the button continue of the modal window never redirects the user to the specific controller-action (MVC ASP.NET) could you please help me

Comment: Is the click function being hit? Perhaps put an alert in the click function to see if its firing.

Comment: it hits, and it seems to be redirecting as well http://www.bootply.com/tZlXyuPmrr redirecting where - thats the question

Comment: I just added an alert window to the click event of the continue button but nothing appears

Comment: is this modal added dinamically? or it is on the dom when the page is rendered?

Comment: @PabloMayora - try changing the Jquery to $(document).on('click', '#btnContinueDelete', function () { . I'm fairly new myself but have experienced binding issues for click events.

Comment: @Wheels73 thanks, but didn't work

Comment: @xploshioOn it's added dinamically

Comment: the @Wheels73 comment is the answer to your question, the thing here is that the element doesn't exist when the event init is fired, so it's not attached to the new elements that you add to the dom. with the wheels73 comment, it will be added to all the elements that have that id but attached to the document that it does exist on that moment. and add it inside $(document).ready just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on("click","#btnContinueDelete",function () {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action(actionName: "TipoEvento", controllerName: "Home")';
});
```

since it is added dynamically.

Comment: thakns, hot should it be if not added automatically